# Какие процессоры поддерживаются форматом файлов ELF на Linux?

Tags: elf, linux

Какие процессоры поддерживаются форматом файлов ELF на Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Формат объектных файлов ELF поддерживает самые разные процессоры от 8-ми до 64-х битных архитектур. Объектные файлы содержат часть управляющих данных в машинно-независимом виде, что дает возможность правильно трактовать их содержимое на разных машинах.